# How to simulate two antennas in 4nec2

Tags: antenna, antenna-theory, vhf, antenna-system, antenna-modeling

I need to simulate 2 helix antennae placed side by side, and see the resultant radiation pattern. But after adding the second antenna with a separate and when I try to simulate 4nec2, only simulated the 1st antenna.

Any thoughts on how to simulate both antennas?

[image: two helix]

[image: Only one is getting simulated]

Comment: As a start, if in practice both antennas are connected to one or more sources of r-f power, you might check your NEC wire model to be sure that those sources are correctly placed, and configured.

Comment: It might be helpful if you edited your question and included the NEC file.

Answer (score 2):

It is more than 15 years ago, that I've done it.
But if I remember correctly, the 3D screenshot you're showing is quite misleading. The pattern is drawn around the 1st antenna / center of coordinate system.
Delete the 2nd antenna and compare the gains to make sure nothing changes at all.